# How to style/animate nested SVG?

Tags: css, svg

I'm learning SVG. This is my animated SVG:

```css
#sky {
  animation: skyColor 10s alternate infinite linear;
}

@keyframes skyColor {
  0% {
    fill: #000000;
  }
  30% {
    fill: #000000;
  }
  40% {
    fill: #303030;
  }
  50% {
    fill: #fffade;
  }
  60% {
    fill: #add1db;
  }
  100% {
    fill: #dcf5fc;
  }
}

#sun {
  r: 10;
  fill: yellow;
}

#bear {
  transform: translate(50px, 50px);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="600" height="400">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="snowHillGradient1" x1="0.25" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fdfdfd"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#e0e0e0"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <linearGradient id="snowHillGradient2" x1="0" x2="0.25" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fcfcfc"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#d2d2d2"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <linearGradient id="snowHillGradient3" x1="0.5" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fcfcfc"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#d6d6d6"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="200" id="sky"/>
  <circle id="sun" cx="150" cy="220">
    <animateMotion dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" path="m 0 0 a 1 1 0 0 1 0 -220 a 1 1 0 0 1 0 220" />
  </circle>

  <path id="moon" fill="#f7f7f7" d="M 0 0 a 9 9 0 1 0 3 15 c -13 2 -13 -14 -3 -15" >
    <animateMotion dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" path="m 150 0 a 1 1 0 0 1 0 220 a 1 1 0 0 1 0 -220" />
  </path>

  <path fill="url(#snowHillGradient1)" stroke="#f0f0f0" stroke-width="0.25" d="M -20 68 l 212 0 c -68 -50 -181 -29 -212 0" style="transform: scale(3);" />
  <path fill="url(#snowHillGradient2)" stroke="#f0f0f0" stroke-width="0.25" d="M -60 85 l 212 0 c -81 -42 -191 -39 -212 0" style="transform: scale(2.2);" />
  <path fill="url(#snowHillGradient3)" stroke="#eaeaea" stroke-width="0.25" d="M 4 85 l 212 0 c -68 -50 -181 -29 -212 0" style="transform: scale(2.5);" />
  <path fill="url(#snowHillGradient2)" stroke="#f0f0f0" stroke-width="0.25" d="M -44 85 l 212 0 c -81 -32 -183 -21 -212 0" style="transform: scale(2.5);" /> 

  <svg width="100" height="100" id="bear">
    <!-- Bear -->
    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#543C23" d="m 35 60 l -20 20 l -4 10 l 0 5 l 78 0 l 0 -5 l -4 -10 l -20 -20 " />

    <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="30" ry="25" fill="#543C23" stroke="black" />

    <ellipse cx="41" cy="45" rx="7" ry="7" fill="white" stroke="black" />
    <ellipse cx="58" cy="45" rx="7" ry="7" fill="white" stroke="black" />
    <ellipse cx="41" cy="44" rx="3" ry="3" fill="black" stroke="none" />
    <ellipse cx="58" cy="44" rx="3" ry="3" fill="black" stroke="none" />
    
    <ellipse cx="49" cy="58" rx="6" ry="4" fill="black" stroke="none" />
    <line x1="49" y1="58" x2="49" y2="68" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />

    <polyline points="34,62 41,67 49,68 57,67 64,62" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />

    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#543C23" d="m 25 40 c -5 -10  0 -15 10 -10" />

    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#543C23" d="m 75 40 c 5 -10 0 -15 -10 -10" />

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" fill="none" />
  </svg>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="200" stroke="black" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

I want to animate/style nested SVG (#bear id).
But even simple

```
  #bear {
    transform: translate(50px, 50px);
  }
```

works only in FireFox! But in Chrome it has no effect.

How can I style/animate nested SVG in Chrome?
Maybe there is some other way to animate nested SVG?
Nested SVG is very convenient due to its own coordinate system.

Comment: You'd have to put a <g> element inside the <svg> element and transform that if you want to have it work in Chrome. Perhaps Chrome will catch up with the SVG 2 specification and Firefox one day and this won't be necessary.

Comment: But this approach limits the possibilities. In a nested SVG, we can apply complex animations to elements without thinking about positioning in an external SVG. And then, on top of the group of internal animations, we can apply another animation from the external SVG.

Comment: OK, [go fix Chrome then](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231535&q=component%3ABlink%3ESVG%20transform&can=2) it is open source after all.

Comment: @RobertLongson The <g> element inside the <svg> worked perfectly in my case. You just saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a nested `<svg>` could be `<symbol>`. A symbol element can also be handled separate to the rest. To show the symbol you then need to use   `<use>` as well -- and that can then be styled (I changed the CSS selector to `#usebear`).

```css
#sky {
  animation: skyColor 10s alternate infinite linear;
}

@keyframes skyColor {
  0% {
    fill: #000000;
  }
  30% {
    fill: #000000;
  }
  40% {
    fill: #303030;
  }
  50% {
    fill: #fffade;
  }
  60% {
    fill: #add1db;
  }
  100% {
    fill: #dcf5fc;
  }
}

#sun {
  r: 10;
  fill: yellow;
}

#usebear {
  transform: translate(50px, 50px);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="600" height="400">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="snowHillGradient1" x1="0.25" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fdfdfd"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#e0e0e0"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <linearGradient id="snowHillGradient2" x1="0" x2="0.25" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fcfcfc"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#d2d2d2"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <linearGradient id="snowHillGradient3" x1="0.5" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fcfcfc"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#d6d6d6"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="200" id="sky"/>
  <circle id="sun" cx="150" cy="220">
    <animateMotion dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" path="m 0 0 a 1 1 0 0 1 0 -220 a 1 1 0 0 1 0 220" />
  </circle>

  <path id="moon" fill="#f7f7f7" d="M 0 0 a 9 9 0 1 0 3 15 c -13 2 -13 -14 -3 -15" >
    <animateMotion dur="20s" repeatCount="indefinite" path="m 150 0 a 1 1 0 0 1 0 220 a 1 1 0 0 1 0 -220" />
  </path>

  <path fill="url(#snowHillGradient1)" stroke="#f0f0f0" stroke-width="0.25" d="M -20 68 l 212 0 c -68 -50 -181 -29 -212 0" style="transform: scale(3);" />
  <path fill="url(#snowHillGradient2)" stroke="#f0f0f0" stroke-width="0.25" d="M -60 85 l 212 0 c -81 -42 -191 -39 -212 0" style="transform: scale(2.2);" />
  <path fill="url(#snowHillGradient3)" stroke="#eaeaea" stroke-width="0.25" d="M 4 85 l 212 0 c -68 -50 -181 -29 -212 0" style="transform: scale(2.5);" />
  <path fill="url(#snowHillGradient2)" stroke="#f0f0f0" stroke-width="0.25" d="M -44 85 l 212 0 c -81 -32 -183 -21 -212 0" style="transform: scale(2.5);" /> 

  <symbol width="100" height="100" id="bear">
    <!-- Bear -->
    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#543C23" d="m 35 60 l -20 20 l -4 10 l 0 5 l 78 0 l 0 -5 l -4 -10 l -20 -20 " />

    <ellipse cx="50" cy="50" rx="30" ry="25" fill="#543C23" stroke="black" />

    <ellipse cx="41" cy="45" rx="7" ry="7" fill="white" stroke="black" />
    <ellipse cx="58" cy="45" rx="7" ry="7" fill="white" stroke="black" />
    <ellipse cx="41" cy="44" rx="3" ry="3" fill="black" stroke="none" />
    <ellipse cx="58" cy="44" rx="3" ry="3" fill="black" stroke="none" />
    
    <ellipse cx="49" cy="58" rx="6" ry="4" fill="black" stroke="none" />
    <line x1="49" y1="58" x2="49" y2="68" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />

    <polyline points="34,62 41,67 49,68 57,67 64,62" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />

    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#543C23" d="m 25 40 c -5 -10  0 -15 10 -10" />

    <path stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#543C23" d="m 75 40 c 5 -10 0 -15 -10 -10" />

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" stroke="red" fill="none" />
  </symbol>
  <use href="#bear" id="usebear"/>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="200" stroke="black" fill="none" />
</svg>
```